# No repository found in Crashlytics install for eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, crashlytics

I'm trying to install the Crashlytics SDK into my Eclipse but I'm getting the following error:

'Installing Software' has encountered a problem.
An error ocurred while collecting items to be installed

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,22.0.1.v201305230001--685705
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package,22.0.1.v201305230001--685705
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.base,22.0.1.v201305230001--685705
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,22.0.1.v201305230001--685705
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay,22.0.1.v201305230001--685705
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,22.0.1.v201305230001--685705
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,22.0.1.v201305230001--685705
```

Is it a problem in the Crashlytics repository? Can somebody help me solve this problem?

Comment: I'm having the same error after getting the invite yesterday, I wasn't able to find a solution. I'll be following this closely.

Comment: I sent them an email trying to get some answer, if they answer I tell you.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

That looks like you may not have ADT installed. But if you do (that was my case), you can try unchecking the box in the attached screenshot and it works perfectly.

[image]

Comment: Eclipse kept complaining my ADT was out of date and it wouldn't let me continue working with an existing project using API 15 because of this.  I got a bunch of errors because wit wouldn't recognize anything in the SDK.  It wouldn't update because it said a repository was invalid.  This solution fixed everything!

Comment: stackoverflow the rescue. Again.

Comment: Still not worked by unchecking it. I am using Fedora 18.

Comment: not able to see the screen shot , Can you specify which flag?

Comment: @Ajay Contatct all updates sites during install to find required software