# Crashlytics crashing adt consistently

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, crashlytics

I followed this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052556/no-repository-found-in-crashlytics-install-for-eclipse) to get crashlytics install. 
ADT runs for about 30-40 secs and crashes every time with a message starting with:

> Application Specific Information: abort() called
>
> Thread 0:: AppKit Thread  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0
>   libjvm.dylib                    0x00000001043a304a
>   CompilationPolicy::must_be_compiled(methodHandle, int) + 32 1
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x00000001044ad8f0
>   JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArgument

Full stack trace is at - https://gist.github.com/prolificcoder/6816185